# Screen size in TBB and fingerprinting

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, panopticlick

I decided to check on TBB panopticlick, and my attention was drawn to the field value "Screen Size and Color Depth", it says:

bits of identifying information - 11,28 /
one in x browsers have this value - 2479,35 /
value - 1920x969x24

Well, ok, it is clear (browser deployed on the entire screen window).

But then, I decided to check out as normal firefox, and then google chrome. And what do I see?

bits of identifying information - 2.31 / 
one in x browsers have this value - 4.97 /
value - 1920x1080x24

Can you tell me: "Do not open TBB to full screen, run in the default window."

Here are the results for the default window:

bits of identifying information - 8.01 /
one in x browsers have this value - 257.61 /
value - 1000x900x24

As can be seen, but also in such a small "typical" window, my browser is unique from the other 250, 250 to 5, not bad, huh?

So, how to fix this (because in the full screen mode to work much more productively)?

I understand that it is not in prefs.js or in something like this...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's exactly what I can tell you: if you're using a Tor browser - use it as it's designed to be. The goal of the default screen size is to make it's users look the same way to enharden fingerprinting. If you need a full-screen, you can use either Tor browser or Firefox, Chrome is not recommended due to it's google nature :) But be warned: you will be looking more distinct and specific, even when using a dedicated VM

Comment: Hmm ... And if I give all parameters to the minimum detectable? If panopticlick determine, for example, that "Within our dataset of several hundred thousand visitors, only one in 200 browsers have the same fingerprint as yours.", I'll still look like specific?

Comment: well, I'd rather say no, if there's no other fingerprinting tokens.